# How to restart PostgreSQL server under CentOS 7

Tags: postgresql, centos-7, pg-hba.conf

I installed PostgreSQL 10.1 under a CentOS 7.3 environment.

The service is started (`postmaster.pid` file present under `/var/lib/pgsql/10/data`), but I need to reload configuration or restart the server following a change in `pg_hba.conf`.

However, trying different commands, I get the following:

```
pg_ctl reload -D /var/lib/pgsql/10/data
bash: pg_ctl: command not found

service postgresql reload
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl reload postgresql.service
Failed to reload postgresql.service: Unit not found.
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found out that you need to specify the ***exact*** name for the PostgreSQL service, which you can find under the list of services, using `systemctl` (also see this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267329/how-do-you-stop-posgresql-on-centos-7)):

```
systemctl list-units|grep postgresql
postgresql-10.service                                                                     loaded active running   PostgreSQL 10 database server
```

Then you can use `service`:

```
service postgresql-10.service reload
```

or

```
service postgresql-10.service restart
```

Alternatively, you can use the `systemctl` command:

```
/bin/systemctl reload postgresql-10.service
```

or

```
/bin/systemctl restart postgresql-10.service
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have sudogoer as a role in postgresql, you can alternatively use:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Comment: This is wrong, the unit is called `postgresql-10`

Comment: This is not wrong. It works for me. Also here's further proof: https://linode.com/docs/databases/postgresql/how-to-install-postgresql-relational-databases-on-centos-7/#peer-authentication

Comment: The .service file can be called anything you want. It's usually located at /usr/lib/systemd/system and can be renamed as you please. If you customize it though, it's recommended to move it to /etc/systemd/system

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql-10
```

---

Or better:

```
$ /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_ctl reload
```

Or first (one-time):

```
    $ sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/bin/pg_ctl
```

and then (every time):

```
    $ pg_ctl reload
```

---

*Note: **`pg_ctl` cannot be run as root**.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your service file is set up so I can't debug your systemd command. It's possible that it's named something different as Sebastien suggests.

As for pg_ctl, that is a result of the installation not adding the directory to the path. (There are reasons for this mentioned in the comments [here](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/11/07/where-is-pgctl-on-centos-6-for-postgres)). There are a few different ways to solve but I recommend just adding `/usr/pgsql-x.x/bin` to the path of the postgres user. Just add 

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-x.x/bin`

to the postgres user's `.bash_profile` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use (PostgresSQL 11 running on MX Linux (Debian 9, Stretch))-

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql status

/etc/init.d/postgresql stop

/etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `/sbin` is part of your path if running the `service` and `systemctl` commands.